# Ubuntu PHP and sqlsrv_connect()

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu

I'm using a class that uses `sqlsrv_connect()` in PHP to connect to a MSSQL database server, but I always get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()
```

I’ve done multiple install methods such as:

```
sudo apt-get install -y freetds-bin freetds-common tdsodbc odbcinst unixodbc php5-sybase
```

Restarted apache but none of them seem to solve the problem of the libraries being added. Can help give some guidance on the problem?

I'm using:

```
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.1 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: May  4 2012 02:20:36)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Linux based PHP does not support the `sqlsrv_*` functions. Those are only provided by the Windows driver. FreeTDS will provide you with access to the old `mssql_*` functions.